# Non-blocking implementation of the Google API client's HttpTransport?

Tags: java, nio, nonblocking, google-api-java-client, google-http-client

I'm running several concurrent API calls, and I was wondering whether a non-blocking implementation of [`HttpTransport`](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.3.1-alpha/com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport.html) exists for Google Api client. Does anybody know ?